# What content-type should be used for XML+XSL presentation?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to render XML+XSL 2.0 in browser, returning `.xml` pages with `application/xml` content type and `.xsl` pages with `text/xml`. Safari is complaining for the main document: "Resource interpreted as document but transferred with MIME type application/xml." (but keeps rendering everything just fine).

I want to get rid of this warning message. What content-types should be used for the XML document?

Comment: Does "XML+XSL 2.0" mean that you use XSLT 2.0? Is there any browser that supports XSLT 2.0?

Comment: No browser support, but Saxon CE (alpha) provides XSLT 2.0 in the browser: http://www.saxonica.com/

Comment: Safari 5 and Chrome 15 work fine with XSLT 2.0 (on Mac)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had success using `text/xml` with the stylesheet as `text/xsl` (or perhaps this is OK as `text/xml` as you have it working).  `text/xsl` is widely recognized, but not "official" (as far as I understand it).

According to RFC 3023: "If an XML document that is, the unprocessed, source XML document is readable by casual users, `text/xml` is preferable to `application/xml`. MIME user agents (and web user agents) that do not have explicit support for `text/xml` will treat it as text/plain, for example, by displaying the XML MIME entity as plain text. `application/xml` is preferable when the XML MIME entity is unreadable by casual users."

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023#page-16

Comment: `text/xsl` for an XML document??

Comment: Sorry - for the stylesheet.  And text/xml for the instance document.

Comment: According to RFC 3023: "If an XML document that is, the unprocessed, source XML document is readable by casual users, text/xml is preferable to application/xml.  MIME user agents (and web user agents) that do not have explicit support for text/xml will treat it as text/plain, for example, by displaying the XML MIME entity as plain text.Application/xml is preferable when the XML MIME entity is unreadable by casual users." http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3023#page-16

Comment: Updated answer to reflect above comments.

Answer (score 9):

Peeking into the WebKit source, it's easy to see what MIME types are considered valid for each resource type. It's not a very big list.

The following 4 MIME types are supported for "Documents":

- `text/html`
- `text/xml`
- `text/plain`
- `application/xhtml+xml`

There are only 2 valid types for stylesheets:

- `text/css`
- `text/xsl`

Obviously, the `text/html`, `text/plain`, and `text/css` types don't really apply here.

If you're really just interested in silencing the warnings, sending the `.xml` document as `text/xml` and the `.xsl` document as `text/xsl` should do the trick.

On the other hand, you concede that everything's rendering fine, so you might consider the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" strategy.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the correct media type for XSLT would actually be `application/xslt+xml`, according to https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#media-type-registration as per the official IANA registry https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml. And that's not new, the registration dates back to at least 2007. However, browser support for `application/xslt+xml` is almost non-existent.

Answer (score -2):

Before any transformation i do this in PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8");
```

the part with uft-8 is important ...

Comment: That would apply if he did server-side transformation of XML to XHTML, and even then it would be problematic (IE/MSHTML does not support that MIME type). There is no "uft-8", but the "utf-8" in your code is only correct if the output actually *is* UTF-8-encoded.  Which is not a requirement for XHTML.  You did not answer the question.